# Can data be distributed to different nodes when Spark reads a large file from S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd

Suppose I have a large data file on S3 and want to load it to Spark cluster to perform some data processing. When I use sc.textFile(filepath) to load the file into RDD, will each node in my cluster store portion of my file RDD and distribute over nodes? Or the whole data file will be stored in one node and replicate over the cluster? What if the file size is larger than the memory of that node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no locality with S3, so Spark can schedule the work anywhere there's space.

However, it will only break the file up for processing if it can be split. Avro, ORC, parquet, CSV all split nicely if not compressed with gz. text files? Not AFAIK

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve! My file is in .bz2 format. So does that we can scale out by increasing nodes if memory in the current cluster is not enough? Also, wondering if Spark creates replicate of data on different nodes?

Comment: I would have a look at the scala source of SparkContext.textFile() to see what it offers to do regarding partitioning, then experiment. Adding more machines will help the work to scale if the file can be partitioned into parts >= the number of machines. It doesn't replicate the input data, but if you save the output, it will generate a file per partition.